# Creating a type-safe Fake using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, babeljs

Suppose I have some type:

```js
type Foo = { id: string, foo: () => string }
```

I would like to create a fake like so:

```js
const foo = new Fake<Foo>()
foo.id // ""
foo.foo() // Returns ""
```

This would be useful for testing and mocking certain third parties. The difficulty here will be to generate real JavaScript from a type alone. Here is an implementation of what a Fake class could look like but it's not type-safe.

```
export class Fake {
  constructor({
    props = {},
    didCallMethod = () => {},
  }: {
    props?: Record<string, any>
    didCallMethod?: (name: string, args: any[]) => void
  } = {}) {
    return new Proxy<any>(
      {},
      {
        get: (target, prop) => {
          if (prop in props) {
            // @ts-expect-error
            return props[prop]
          }

          if (prop in target) {
            return target[prop]
          }
          return (...args: any[]) => {
            return didCallMethod(String(prop), args)
          }
        },
      }
    )
  }
}
```

I think this would have to be a babel preprocessing step?

Answer (score 0):

A few months back I had a similar problem. I ended up doing this:

```
type Props<T extends object> = Partial<{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}>;
function mock<T extends object>(props: Props<T>): T {
  return props as T;
}
```

What I like from this is that you get back an object that TS perceives as the one you are mocking. In addition to this, it also provide assistance while working on the `props`.

For example:

```
class Greeter {
  public greet(name: string): string {
    return `[${new Date().toString()}]: Hello ${name}`;
  }
}

function greetWorld(greeter: Greeter): void {
  console.log(greeter.greet('World'));
}

const greeter = new Greeter();
greetWorld(greeter); // It works (of course)

const mockedGreeter = mock<Greeter>({ greet: (name) => `[Time]: Hello ${name}` });
greetWorld(mockedGreeter) // It also works but with a predictable output!
```

[Take a look at the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=44&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwDwBUoQB7AgOwBNkoEAjAKwgGNgA+KAXlgEM5gBLFgG1QG8A2gGkoHfFADWEEAgBmUdAF0AXAuGKAvnQDcAWABQsgK75aHBOIC2CahIxZcBYqUo16ACjCIUq+EjTodACUqph8BlBQcBDARnDiXv5QLCToevoaBgbU3CkkAOLRMRBwUOH6kWBGZNwc1FAA5kXA7vgslhCqyMBwYg0hUN29+A1lEZFRMXHiAAYCACR8+BAA7lAAIix47kEAdMAIAMo9fTsaKlAAEhDc3AhQi20dGjPpkZkZWYYmZhaNzQB1BBwbiEdxNCDFOCqQqQvBwAYANwQHEIYwqUGoFmQCG4EF2dwa4OaJV2EJi7gA5ECQYRKUEgukPtlscB-nCSkwoMs1rCoTt0uTgDTQcSOQjtFAAPRSqAASTZK2BEhI7jkmIQcWQECCXyx+G6UGstgghD58K5xrs5pKdHcfHZMVUrXaOqYDDm6A4HQu11u90erpeUA0jIMQpFYKtpptCOlsoVyW4OKgSrgKoAhAYgA).

This method even supports interfaces (which was the reason I needed it)!

```
interface Car {
  turnEngineOn(): string;
}

const car = mock<Car>({ turnEngineOn: () => 'vroom vroom' });
console.log(car.turnEngineOn());
```

[Another playground to look at](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwDwBUoQB7AgOwBNkoEAjAKwgGNgA+KAXlgEM5gBLFgG1QG8A2gGkoHfFADWEEAgBmUdAF0AXAuGKAvnQDcAWABQsgK75aHBOIC2CahIxZcBYqUo16ACjCIUq+EjTodACUqph8BlBQcBDARnDiXv5QLCToevoaBgZieHCyLNTQAMJsUOH6kbHxAKL4AOZiEADy+O4hUMjAcGJ16Zn6BtQWnVDUpczWtqglcHTufFBV+LUN+M34qm1MDADkAG6ICJZQBwhHO1AaQelD+MgI3BAAdNwIde5jcE9LK40tbdcDEA)

Warning: After all of this, I feel like I must warn you that there might be libraries that do some of this already with better support. I couldn't find a way to mock interfaces tho. A couple of problems with this approach are that you don't get deep `props` support (although it should be fairly easy to add) plus it requires some care as you are re-implementing the objects yourself. However, for a testing suite I found it works great!

--- Edit ---

I've found a way to improve it to only have to reimplement the needed functionality:

```
type Props<T extends object> = Partial<{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}>;
function mock<T extends object>(original: T, reimplemented: Props<T>): T {
  const clone = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(original)), original)
  Object.assign(clone, reimplemented);
  return clone;
}
```

It basically works by cloning the original object and assigning the reimplementations on top.

[Mandatory playground to check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwDwBUoQB7AgOwBNkoEAjAKwgGNgA+KAXlgEM5gBLFgG1QG8A2gGkoHfFADWEEAgBmUdAF0AXAuGKAvnQDcAWABQsgK75aHBOIC2CahIxZcBYqUo16ACgRwOAczE9VdAAaKDgIDkswbghLAjxCVXgkNHQ6AEpAqD4DKChqC2RgPO4LaGYAeVdaADoWZGRffHdKqhrqMJY8Zqrgap8IYCTgBFBIctlPbz98HjS0kK9ff240nKgWt1r6xvdqEvwIELCIqJi4iEI0vX1csOAjOHE90uuNAwM9upIAYTYstbARjI3A41Cg90eAFF8NMIOUmhkoIVvDD-jdcqEBg9xAByABuiAQligBIQRJx11yb30AKBILBEPw0Nh4wmiORYh8aIxmMZUBxACoGtF8EV8AgOMgIMgBRS1tTqR8CkVqH9mAcAO5QX5wdxXJX4QpQay2C46pjGmx2HV0XZsEJ8cHY5liOGyWSqPVMBgAIgAksAcSRChxuNxQiZ8JyAIQ+qAafU0-T5Q0IaLVEo+O1waqMl0HeF6xMp5BpiAZhBZ1U5vMw12sovXA2l9OZ9wmqSEHW5511gsI4sFMsVrMds1sHtQvtutlXIA).

Comment: Right but I want it to generate all the methods and properties, I don't want to have to provide defaults

Comment: Check the latest update. I realised you where using Proxy for this reason so I updated my answer to have a similar approach.